# PayPal order automatically cancelled before payment?

Tags: magento, paypal

I have this weird problem with paypal_standard in magento:
Sometimes a order gets cancelled automatically, but then the payment arrives.
This fucks up the status completely! The order then is automatically set to complete, but it is not shipped and shipping is not possible (because it is cancelled).
Here is the log from one such order:
[image: Order log from problematic order]

What could be the reason for that automatic cancellation?

As you can see, the order was cancelled less than four minutes after creation?!?

Comment: Have you had this problem more than once? I've just experienced it and I'm wondering if Timo's answer is the cause.

Comment: I had this maybe four times since asking the question here. I am not sure what exactly is the reason for it.

Comment: Anyone found a fix? I am still havin this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this by clicking on 'cancel' and 'pay now' almost simultaneously on the Paypal payment site. The cancel gets back faster to Magento, resulting in a canceled order. When the IPN arrives, the order is already cancelled. 
According to a quick scan of Paypal's documentation it is not possible to reject an IPN. So it seems to me that only way of handling this correctly is to automatically refund the money when the IPN is received on a cancelled order.